# How did "li" come to mean "here" in Cape Verdean Creole?

Tags: etymology, portuguese, creoles

The words *li* and *la* in Cape Verdean Creole look parallel to the Portuguese words *ali* and *lá*. There's just one problem: *li* and *ali* are opposites. *Li* means "here", while *ali* means "there". There are differences between *ali* and *lá*, with *ali* being used to refer to locations near the person being spoken to, but it certainly doesn't mean "here"; Portuguese uses *aqui* or *cá* to express that, and Creole uses *la* to express *ali*.

Does *li* come from *ali*? If so, how did it come to mean the opposite? If not, what is its etymology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with these languages, so I can't give a complete answer to your question.

I just wanted to point out that "opposites" is a pretty strong term for two words with such similar meanings as "here" and "there". They're both [demonstratives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonstrative#Distal_and_proximal_demonstratives); it's relatively simple for demonstratives to change with regard to proximal/distal usage. E.g. the French word "ici" means "here", and you'll usually see "là" defined as "there", but in fact "là" is also commonly used to express the idea of "here". ([Why use là instead of ici?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11982/why-use-l%C3%A0-instead-of-ici))

It sounds like you say Portuguese has a three-way distinction between *aqui/cá* "here" (proximal), *ali* "there" (medial), and *lá* (distal), while Cape Verdean Creole has a two-way system *li* (proximal) vs. *la* (distal). It's very easy for this to develop from the Portuguese system by simply dropping the Portuguese proximal pronouns and shifting the remaining ones to fill their semantic space.

Comment: Adding to this: while I was studying (Brazilian) Portuguese I was taught that while the usual demonstratives went *este - esse - aquele* etc. (the same system as in my native Spanish, BTW), it was rather common to employ the medial deictics instead of the proximal ones. So I don't see this happening in Caboverdiano as strange.

Comment: I just put two and two together: the demonstrative pronouns mirror exactly what you're talking about here. (*Es li* means *this*, rather than using a cognate of *este*.) This must be the answer.